# Stripe Receipt URL for invoices paid outside of Stripe

Tags: python-3.x, stripe-payments

The title if self explanatory. The receipt URL is found in the Charge object, but because the invoice was paid outside of Stripe, the chargeid is null in the invoice object. So how do I get a receipt for an invoice that was paid outside of Stripe and therefore there is no chargeid?

The Stripe web interface allows you to download a receipt PDF for an invoice, but I cannot figure out how to accomplish this using the API.

This is a mockup and it's how you normally get the receipt URL and it works.

```
charge_id = invoice.get('charge')
# if payment was through Stripe
if charge_id:
    charge = stripeObject.getChargeObject(charge_id)
    if 'receipt_url' in charge:
        print(charge['receipt_url'])


# if payment was outside of Stripe, how do I get a receipt URL?
else:

    ??????
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `invoice_pdf` property on the Invoice object which will contain the Invoice PDF URL: https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-invoice_pdf

Comment: This is just the invoice and not a receipt. There is a big difference.
The customer will see "Amount Due $xxx" in the PDF, even though the invoice was already paid.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `invoice_pdf` is actually what you want, because that's the open Invoice pdf, i.e. **'$XX due on XX'**.

If you want the receipt pdf, i.e. **'$XX paid on XX'** for an Invoice that has no charge, then there is really only one solution: redirecting the customer to the `hosted_invoice_url`.

This is what it looks like for a $50.00 Invoice that was paid out of band:

[image]

Comment: I was thinking about using the hosted_invoice_url as a last resort. It's not a bad solution, but I wanted to know if there was a way using the API. Looks like there isn't.